# Gradle Multi Project - apply "clean" task for each java library project before "jar"

Tags: java, gradle

as it was mentioned in the title I have Gradle Multi-Project contains java-library. I cannot find way to add `clean` and `javadoc` task before `jar` task execution.

This is my current build.gradle file

```
apply plugin:'java'

task printRootProjectInfo{
    println '----- Project info -----'
    println 'Project name: ' + rootProject.name
    println 'Subprojects: '
    subprojects.findAll { subproject -> println "    $subproject.name" }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects{
    jar {
        dependsOn clean
    }
}

//todo: add `clean` task before each `jar` task for subprojects
//def printProjectInfo  = {
//    println '====== Start processing subproject ======'
//    println "______ $rootProject.name ==>  $project.name"
//}
```

I found code on StackOverFlow where someone manage to invoke simple print command for each project but cannot find example with `dependOn` syntax.

I try to use syntax:

```
subprojects{
    jar {
        dependsOn clean
    }
}
```

but it seems to have no effect.

Could you provide an example?

I use Gradle 5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs answer for this, here is syntax which works for me:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'

    tasks.jar.dependsOn("clean")
}
```